# How can I create a file which containing 10 random numbers in Linux Shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to create a Linux command which creates a file containing 10 random numbers.

This is a solution to generate 10 random numbers;

```
RANDOM=$$
for i in `seq 10`
do
echo $RANDOM
done
```

It is working to generate random numbers but how can I combine this with 'touch' command? Should I create a loop?

Comment: NO, simply redirect the output to a file. `./yourscript > file`

Comment: @RamazanErikli : What would be the purpose of `touch`? The purpose of `touch` is to modify the timestamp of a file, respectively to ensure the existence of a file (i.e. create an **empty** file if no file of this name exists yet). Both usecases are unrelated to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Using touch? Like this?

```
touch file.txt && RANDOM=$$
for i in `seq 10`
  do
  echo $RANDOM
done >> file.txt
```

Not sure why you need touch though, this will also work:

```
for i in `seq 10`; do echo $RANDOM; done > file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use >> to write to file, $1 is first argument of your .sh file

```
FILE=$1
RANDOM=$$
for i in `seq 10`
do
echo $RANDOM >> $FILE
echo "\n" >> $FILE
done
```

Comment: You may forgot to put `$` before `FILE` (and double-quoting it).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [head(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html) and [od(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html) or [GNU gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) with [random(4)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html).

For example, perhaps

```
 head -20c /dev/random | od -s > /tmp/tenrandomnumbers.txt
```